# How to find $n$ in combinations question, given the ratio of two $^n C_r$

Tags: combinatorics

The original question was:

> The ratio of the number of combinations of $2n+2$ different objects taken $n$ at a time to the number of combinations of $2n-2$ different objects taken $n$ at a time is $99:7$. Find the value of $n$.

I've arrived at: $$\frac{(2n+2)!(n-2)!}{(2n-2)!(n+2)!}=\frac{99}{7} $$
But I'm unsure of how to progress past here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\displaystyle \frac{( 2n+2) !( n-2) !}{( 2n-2) !( n+2) !} \ =\frac{( 2n+2)( 2n+1)( 2n)( 2n-1)( 2n-2) !( n-2) !}{( 2n-2) !( n+2)( n+1)( n)( n-1)( n-2) !} \ $

$\displaystyle \frac{( 2n+2)( 2n+1)( 2n)( 2n-1)}{( n+2)( n+1)( n)( n-1)} \ =\ \frac{4( n+1)( 2n+1)( n)( 2n-1)}{( n+2)( n+1)( n)( n-1)}$

$\displaystyle \frac{4( 2n+1)( 2n-1)}{( n+2)( n-1)} =\frac{4\left( 4n^{2} -1\right)}{( n+2)( n-1)} =99/7$

$\displaystyle 28\left( 4n^{2} -1\right) =99\left( n^{2} +n-2\right) \ \Longrightarrow \ 13n^{2} -99n+170\ =0\ \Longrightarrow \ n=5$

Answer (score 0):

*Hint*

First simplification

$\dfrac{(2n+2)(2n+1)(2n)(2n-1)}{(n+2)(n+1)(n)(n-1)}=\dfrac{99}7$

Second simplification

$\dfrac{(4)(2n+1)(2n-1)}{(n+2)(n-1)} = \dfrac{99}7$

Now numerator must be divisble by $11$ and denominator by $7$, so....

Answer (score 0):

One of $2n+2,2n+1,2n,2n-1$ must be divisible by $11$. By inspection, $n=5$.